# Questions about costmap_2D

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been reading up on the costmap_2D package and I just can't seem to wrap my head about it. Here are a couple questions that hopefully someone on here can help me understand.

1. What is the difference between the `OccupancyGrid` published on `/map` by the Gmapping package and the `OccupancyGrid` published on `/grid` by the costmap_2D package? My understanding is that costmap_2D provides a way to update a map at real-time, but when I run the `gmapping_demo.launch` file in turtlebot_navigation, the map is also updated at real-time. So why is costmap_2D needed if the Gmapping package can build and update a map at real-time?
2. Where is the costmap_2D package actually run? The wiki makes me think that it is run in one of the navigation launch files, and that it is needed by the move_base node. However, when I run the `amcl_demo.launch` file, I do not see costmap_2D in the results of `rosnode list`. When I run `rqt_graph` with the amcl demo running, the only topics I see relevant to costmaps are published by `move_base` (they are `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap`, `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates`, `/move_base/local_costmap/costmap`, and `/move_base/local_costmap/costmap_updates`), but they have no subscribers.

If anyone can help me understand, I would be very grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249917/questions-about-costmap_2d/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. The model used by costmap_2d is much simpler/faster than gmapping. The costmap relies on localization for accurate position estimates, whereas gmapping keeps track of many more factors to publish a map and a position estimate. The costmap is primarily used when you have already built a static map and want to track your position within it using AMCL, while still performing dynamic obstacle avoidance.
2. Costmap_2d is usually not run by itself (although it can be). It is typically run from within move_base, with its results published as a convenience, not necessarily to be used by other nodes, thus explaining the lack of subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1